# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash

I am trying to run this command:

```
java -jar -XX:-TieredCompilation node_modules/google-closure-compiler/compiler.jar --flagfile="/tmp/499a750e-98bc-4afa-b333-fb08fa71351e" --js=/home/ubuntu/santa-tracker-web/components/closure-library/closure/goog/base.js --externs=node_modules/google-closure-compiler/contrib/externs/google_universal_analytics_api.js --compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --warning_level=VERBOSE --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT --language_out=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT --define=santaAPIRequest.BASE="https://santa-api.appspot.com/" --output_wrapper=(function(){%output%}).call(window); --rewrite_polyfills=false --generate_exports=true --export_local_property_definitions=true --jscomp_warning=accessControls --jscomp_warning=const --jscomp_warning=visibility --js_output_file="santa.min.js"
```

It is actually an error from a gulpfile, but I have narrowed this issue down to this specific line of code here which creates said issue. 
It complains about the syntax - but to my eye I can't catch what seems to be the issue.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Including the actual screen lines showing calling it and error message after us always the best... Others might spit something you missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use quotes to protect

```
function(){%output%}).call(window);
```

from the shell:

```
java -jar -XX:-TieredCompilation node_modules/google-closure-compiler/compiler.jar --flagfile="/tmp/499a750e-98bc-4afa-b333-fb08fa71351e" --js=/home/ubuntu/santa-tracker-web/components/closure-library/closure/goog/base.js --externs=node_modules/google-closure-compiler/contrib/externs/google_universal_analytics_api.js --compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --warning_level=VERBOSE --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT --language_out=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT --define=santaAPIRequest.BASE="https://santa-api.appspot.com/" --output_wrapper='(function(){%output%}).call(window);' --rewrite_polyfills=false --generate_exports=true --export_local_property_definitions=true --jscomp_warning=accessControls --jscomp_warning=const --jscomp_warning=visibility --js_output_file="santa.min.js"
```